# Herkunft "einen.."?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Verstehe all die Redewendungen aber nicht die Herkunft der Form:

> - Eine rauchen
> - Einen an der Waffel haben
> - Einen trinken

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es handelt sich um [Ellipsen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Linguistik)), bei denen das jeweilige Substantiv ausgelassen wurde. Beim ersten und beim dritten Beispiel etwa:

> - eine<s>n</s> (Zigarette) rauchen
> - einen (Schnaps) trinken

Laut der [Gesellschaft für deutsche Sprache](https://gfds.de/bedeutung-von-einen-an-der-waffel-haben/) spielt der Ausdruck „einen an der Waffel haben“ auf einen Schaden im Kopf an. Daher kann man das zweite Beispiel wie folgt interpretieren:

> - einen (Schaden) am Kopf / an der Waffel haben